# Impossible to pip install pysphinx

Tags: python, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to use Pysphynx to run the following speech-to-text transcription code. It seems that there is just no way to install pysphinx, I get the standard error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysphynx (from versions: none)

and I did not find any guidance on internet. What would you advise me? (I installed, beforehand, other packages such as pocketsphinx) Is pysphinx obsolete?

```
pip install pysphinx
import pysphinx

# Create a SpeechRecognizer object
recognizer = pysphinx.SpeechRecognizer(language='fr-FR')

# Load the audio file
audio_file = output_path
audio = pysphinx.AudioFile(audio_file)

# Transcribe the audio into text
text = recognizer.transcribe(audio)

# Print the transcribed text
print(text)

with open('transcription.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

I installed, beforehand, other packages such as pocketsphinx. I have tried to run the code on colab jupyternotebook. I have tried pip install --find-links https://pypi.org/simple pysphinx . The same issue arises each time.

Comment: There is no package called "pysphynx" in pypi.org

Comment: use `pip install sphinx` in your command line and please refer [this](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html) documentation guide for more info.